# Is there a pyrophoric subtance that ANY kind of vertebrate could store in a special organ?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, fauna, dragons

I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186806/plausible-for-my-dragon-to-shoot-fire-from-its-rear) previously, but didn't receive any answers that satisfied me, so I'm going to simplify it:

**Is there a pyrophoric substance (liquid, gas or solid) that is reactive to air that *any* kind of vertebrate animal could store in a special organ**?

Please give me a straight answer: either "there's no such thing", or the name of the compound that can be stored (with some explanations).

Comment: It's established that on the internet using bold and capital is the equivalent of shouting.

Comment: "it seems that I'm getting answers that doesn't answer to my question" - you only received one answer, and at no point have you explained *why* it doesn't answer your question. Reposting the question and repeatedly resorting to yelling seems uncalled for.

Answer (score 1):

A pyrophoric liquid that may work is [Triethylborane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethylborane), it was used to initially ignite the fuel for the BlackBird's turbojets as it **reliably** ignited in air.
It burns with  a bright green flame.

[image]

While it isn't acidic or basic it is a strong reducing agent, so your special organ would have to be resistant to reduction, maybe using fluorocarbons like Teflon.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

any, as long as the creature does not let any material that it reacts with it go near, another could by chlorine trifluoride, while it does not burn in contact with oxygen, it does with water

edit: this is also something i used for my dragon model